# Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: Couldn't create directory ${system:java.io.tmpdir}\${hive.session.id}_resources

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop3

I run `Hadoop 3.0.0-alpha1` on windows and added `Hive 2.1.1` to it. When I try to open the hive beeline with the `hive` command I get an error:

```
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: 
Couldn't create directory ${system:java.io.tmpdir}\${hive.session.id}_resources
```

Whats wrong?

I run `mysql` as metastore for Hive and added the required files in HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hive
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
```

After that I changed the permissions:

```
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/hive
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp
```

`YARN` and `DFS` deamons are running as well as `mysql`, the mysql jdbc-driver is known to hadoop as well as to hive.

Comment: Look at the Hive documentation about "Configuration properties" https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties and specifically `hive.exec.scratchdir` and the 3+ "scratchdir" props.

Comment: Also remember that `java.io.tmpdir` is a **local** directory -- plain Java code cannot use HDFS!

Answer (score 2):

replace this particular configuration in your **hive-site.xml**

```
<value>${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${hive.session.id}_resources</value>
```

replace with

```
<property>
 <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
  <!--
     <value>${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${hive.session.id}_resources</value>
   -->
  <value>/home/hduser/hive/tmp/${hive.session.id}_resources</value>
  <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system.</description>
</property>
```