# Configure Hive with hadoop installed on windows

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have installed hadoop 2.x on my windows 10. And all services are running fine. Now I want to run hive 2.1 with this hadoop setup. I have configured mysql db with hive for meta store service in hive-site.xml. I have also set the HIVE_HOME in system variables. But when navigating to hadoop folder and running hive I am getting following error:

```
    ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hive/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.1-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hive/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/namaagarwal/Desktop/hadoop-2.6.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: Couldn't create directory ${system:java.io.tmpdir}\${hive.session.id}_resources
Beeline version 2.1.1 by Apache Hive
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: Couldn't create directory ${system:java.io.tmpdir}\${hive.session.id}_resources
Connection is already closed.
```

I don't know what I am missing. 
Here is what I have added in hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hiveuser</value>
<description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>hivepwd</value>
<description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
 <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
 <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
  </property>
```

And My hive-env.sh I have added following properties:

```
HADOOP_HOME=C:\Users\namaagarwal\Desktop\hadoop-2.6.2
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=C:\hive\apache-hive-2.1.1-bin\conf
```

Comment: You should probably use Hadoop 2.7, but it's `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive` because `/user` doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am able to create the directories. But still the error persists while connecting to hive.

Comment: Add your Hive site XML and hive-env.sh

Comment: I have added the properties

Comment: Hmm. Somewhere that `${system:java.io.tmpdir}\${hive.session.id}` needs to be expanded to an actual value. Just not sure where. I thought it was Hive env

Comment: in Hive-site.xml I found that property. What value needs to be set for this?? windows local directory path or some hdfs path??

Comment: It should be the local filesystem. At least, that's where the Java tmpdir exists

Comment: Same error here https://stackoverflow.com/q/42690210/2308683

Comment: I have replaced all the "java.io.tmpdir" value with some windows local directory path. Now I am getting this error:
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient